# Modify array to make it usable with RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input array which contains various domains:

```js
var sites = ["site2.com", "site2.com", "site3.com"];
```

I need to check, whether certain string `domainName` matches one of these sites. I used
`indexOf` which worked fine, however problem occured when certain `domainName` was shown with subpage, e.g.
`subpage.site1.com`.
I tried to use `some` method with RegExp testing instead:

```js
if(sites.some(function(rx) { return rx.test(domainName); })
```

however the first problem was that I needed to change `""` for every element to `"\\"` to make it work with RegExp:

```js
var sites = [/site1.com/, /site2.com/, /site3.com/];
```

while I want to keep array with quotation marks for end-user.

Second problem was that it returns `true` for in cases where compared `domainName` is not in array, but partially its name contains is part of element in array, for example `anothersite1.com` with `site1.com`. It's rare case but happens.

I can modify my input array with RegExp will start and end with `^$` escape characters, but it will complicate it even more, especially that I will need to also add `([a-z0-9]+[.])` to match subpages.

I tried to use `replace` to change `"foo"` to `\foo\`, but I was unable since quation marks defines array elements. Also I tried to use `replace` with `concat` to merge string with escape characters to achieve element looking like RegExp formula from `site1.com` to `^([a-z0-9]+[.])*site1\.com$` but got issues with escaping characters.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this goal?

Comment: You can specify a word boundary at the beginning of the domain name to account for subdomains, such as `\bsite1\.com$`

Answer (score 1):

You can build a regex from the sites array and do a single regex test:

```js
const sites = ["site1.com", "site2.com", "site3.com"];
const sitesRegex = new RegExp(
  '\\b(' +
  sites.map(site => site.replace(/([\\\.(){}])/g, '\\$1')).join('|') +
  ')$'
);
console.log('sitesRegex: ' + sitesRegex);
// tests:
['foo.com', 'notsite1.com', 'site1.com', 'www.site1.com'].forEach(site => {
  console.log(site + ' => ' + sitesRegex.test(site));
});
```

Output:

```
sitesRegex: /\b(site1\.com|site2\.com|site3\.com)$/
foo.com => false
notsite1.com => false
site1.com => true
www.site1.com => true
```

Explanation of `.replace()` regex:

- `(` -- capture group 1 start
- `[\\\.(){}]` -- character class with regex chars that need to be escaped
- `)` -- capture group 1 end
- `g` flag -- global (match multiple times)

Explanation of resulting `/\b(site1\.com|site2\.com|site3\.com)$/` regex:

- `\b` -- word boundary
- `(` -- group start
- `site1\.com|site2\.com|site3\.com` -- logically `OR`ed and escaped sites
- `)` -- group end
- `$` -- anchor at end of string

Comment: Interesting matchin, I've one question regarding `'\\$1'`. I understand "$" itself, but I don't fully understand "$1", i.e. why when using replace makes that  only "$" appears at the end of the expression regex formula, and not at the end of each element (site) separated by OR? if I the correctly, isn't "$1" used to get the first capture group and insert end of line escape $? And the "site" contains only one group because is standalone element of sites? Could you briefly explain it?

Comment: The first parameter of `.replace()` has a regex with a capture group. You reference the captured char in the second parameter as `$1`. The `\\ ` prefix will escape the captured character. For example the `.` char will be escaped to `\.` (notice that in a string literal you write `\\ ` to get `\ `)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think regex is needed here. You could temporarily prefix both the domainName and the site with a dot, and then call `endsWith`:

```js
const sites = ["site1.com", "site2.com", "site3.com"];

const isValid = domainName => 
    sites.some(site => ("." + domainName).endsWith("." + site));

// demo
console.log(isValid("site1.com")); // true
console.log(isValid("subpage.site1.com")); // true
console.log(isValid("othersite1.com")); // false
```

Comment: It's so easy workaround solution I didn't even thought it was possible. Thanks. I guess I could use an analogous rule with startsWith to also catch subdirectories. I'm right?

Comment: Yes, depending on what you mean with subdirectories (subdomains?).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this requirement by using [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) along with [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
var sites = ["site1.com", "site2.com", "site3.com"];

const str = "subpage.site3.com";

const isDomainAvailable = sites.filter(domain => {
    const regEx = new RegExp(`^([a-z0-9]+[.])*${domain}$`);
  return regEx.test(str);
});

console.log(isDomainAvailable.length ? 'matched' : 'not matched');
```

RegEx explanantion **:**

`^` - It matches the beginning of a line 
`(` - Opening Parentheses for Grouping 
`[a-z0-9]+` - Matches alphanumeric characters which can be occurred one or more time (`+`). 
`[.]` - Matches a dot (`.`) 
`)` - Closing Parentheses for Grouping 
`*` - match zero or more of the preceding character. 
`${domain}` - This is our domain name getting dynamically from the `sites` array. 
`$` - It matches the end of a line

Comment: You need to test for word boundary, this gives a false positive for `www.mysite1.com`

Comment: @PeterThoeny It is working fine for `www.mysite1.com` as well. Here is the demo jsfiddle link. https://jsfiddle.net/fq10e368/

Comment: Yes, that is the point, read the OP's "Second problem was" paragraph

Comment: @PeterThoeny - Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer. I hope it will work as per the expectation now.